# How can I redirect tail -f output to curl (HTTP stream)

Tags: linux, shell, http, curl

I want to collect realtime logs from embedded devices. The device have limited command. It would be great if I can do it by a shell script.

So, can I do something like this `tail -f /var/logs/some-log.log | curl -X POST --data-urlencode @- http://<log-collaction.website>`?

I have tried many ways, but all failed. For example:

```
ping www.google.com | while read -r LINE; do curl -X POST --silent --data-binary $LINE "http://localhost:8080/"; done
```

The above command works, but it will post messages line by line. However, I think the performance is not good if I have a lot of content to send.

I know HTTP/1.1 support chunked encoding. How can I redirect a program's stdout to `curl` or a HTTP stream (maybe long connection?).

Thanks

Comment: Try named pipe?

Comment: The issue is that you need to tell curl _when_ to consider a payload package finished and send it. WIth your current attempt it will wait forever, since the `tail` command never terminates, just like your terminal "hangs" with the `tail -f` until you terminate the process.

Comment: I can think of two options: chunk the data into larger pieces for multiple curl invocations, or use a different protocol, like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

Answer (score 4):

You can use a tool like [buffer](http://www.hello-penguin.com/software.htm) (or perhaps even better [mbuffer](http://www.maier-komor.de/mbuffer.html)) to combine both strategies.

```
tail -f  /var/logs/some-log.log | buffer | while read -r LINE; do curl -X POST --silent --data-binary $LINE "http://localhost:8080/"; done
```

This reduces the number of HTTP requests by curl to your webservice (but possibly makes you lose some logs when your connection dies).

However, I agree with Nick Russo that implementing websockets might be a better idea altogether.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think the "while read" structure will continue to break the stream into lines so curl is run just as many times, right? If lines aren't important, perhaps something like LINE=$(dd count=100) could be used instead of read?

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. another answer uses `dd` in a clever way to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the beginning of a chunking strategy that doesn't care about line breaks:

```
while sleep .1; do uptime; done | while LINE=$(dd iflag=fullblock count=2); do echo "$LINE"; done
```

The first `while loop` is just a dummy data generator to make this example trivial to try out. The `echo` at the end stands in for the curl command.

And here's a strategy that *does* care about line breaks:

```
#!/bin/bash

count=0
while sleep .1; do uptime; done | while read -r LINE
do
  count=$[count+1]
  if test "$count" -ge 10
  then
    echo "$ACCUMULATOR"
    ACCUMULATOR="$LINE"
    count=0
  else
    ACCUMULATOR+="
$LINE"
  fi
done
```